# UITableView Selection onLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have this tableView:

[image: Image1]

and it works great, I'm using this to filter data received from an http request. I'd like to save selection when I change view and reset it when I return back. I tried (see the code commented) but I have nil error.
Can someone please help me or explain me how to do?

This is my code:

```
// MARK: TableView
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

// Customize header
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {
    let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18))
    let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18))
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)
    let string: String = names[section]
    label.text = string
    label.textColor = .redColor()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    view.addSubview(label)
    view.backgroundColor = ColorHex().UIColorFromHex(0xEEEEEE)
    return view
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    var number: Int!

    switch section {
    case 0:
        number = 1 //reset filter
        break
    case 1:
        number = statusesDict.count
        break
    case 2:
        number = queuesDict.count
        break
    case 3:
        number = typesDict.count
        break
    case 4:
        number = severitiesDict.count
    default:
        break
    }

    return number
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell: TicketsFilterCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTicketFilter", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TicketsFilterCell

    cell.delegate = self

    if self.selectedIndexPathArray.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.switchFilter.setOn(true, animated: false)
    } else {
        cell.switchFilter.setOn(false, animated: false)
    }


    if(indexPath.section == 0) {

        let text = "Resetta tutti i filtri"

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    } else if(indexPath.section == 1) {

        let text = statusesDict[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    } else if(indexPath.section == 2) {

        let text = queuesDict[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    } else if(indexPath.section == 3) {

        let text = typesDict[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    } else if (indexPath.section == 4) {

        let text = severitiesDict[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    }


    return cell

}

//change value to true for edit tableView rows
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return false
}


//show selection
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    if let index = self.selectedIndexPathArray.indexOf(indexPath) {
        self.selectedIndexPathArray.removeAtIndex(index)
    } else {
        self.selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath)
    }

    let cell = self.tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TicketsFilterCell
    cell.toggleSwitch()


}

func switchButtonTapped(WithStatus status: Bool, ForCell cell: TicketsFilterCell) {
    let indexPath = self.tableview .indexPathForCell(cell)

    if (status == true) {

        if self.selectedIndexPathArray.indexOf(indexPath!) == nil {
            self.selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath!)
        }


        //update dictSelected
        switch (self.tableview.indexPathForCell(cell)!.section) {
        case 0:
            print("section 0, reset all filter")
            self.dictSelectedReset.updateValue(true, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        case 1:
            //take data from status
            print("section 1, value -> \(statusesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]) for row \(String(indexPath!.row))")
            self.dictSelectedStatus.updateValue(statusesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]!, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        case 2:
            //take data from queue
            print("section 2, value -> \(queuesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]) for row \(String(indexPath!.row))")
            self.dictSelectedQueue.updateValue(queuesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]!, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        case 3:
            //take data from type
            print("section 3, value -> \(typesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]) for row \(String(indexPath!.row))")
            self.dictSelectedType.updateValue(typesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]!, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        case 4:
            //take data from severity
            print("section 4, value in -> \(severitiesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]) for row \(String(indexPath!.row))")
            self.dictSelectedSeverity.updateValue(severitiesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]!, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
    else {

        if let index = self.selectedIndexPathArray.indexOf(indexPath!) {
            self.selectedIndexPathArray.removeAtIndex(index)
        }


        //update dictSelected
        //if exist, delete re-tapped

        switch (self.tableview.indexPathForCell(cell)!.section) {
        case 0:
            if (dictSelectedReset.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedReset.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        case 1:
            if (dictSelectedStatus.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedStatus.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        case 2:
            if (dictSelectedQueue.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedQueue.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        case 3:
            if (dictSelectedType.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedType.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        case 4:
            if (dictSelectedSeverity.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedSeverity.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

and this is the code for cells:

```
protocol CellProtocol : class {
func switchButtonTapped(WithStatus status : Bool, ForCell cell : TicketsFilterCell)
}
class TicketsFilterCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var textFilter: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var switchFilter: UISwitch!

weak var delegate : CellProtocol!

class var reuseIdentifier: String? {
    get {
        return "TicketsFilterCell"
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


//  Uncomment here to show switches that are preselected on load

//    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
//        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
//        self.delegate .switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: selected, ForCell: self)
//    }



@IBAction func switchTapped(sender: UISwitch) {

    self.delegate.switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: sender.on, ForCell: self)

}

// select UISwitch and change status
func toggleSwitch() {
    if self.switchFilter.on {
        self.switchFilter .setOn(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        self.switchFilter .setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
    self.delegate.switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: self.switchFilter.on, ForCell: self)
}

}
```

I really don't know how to do it right..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem you have is not clear. Have you tried saving your array and loading data from the same array when the view is active.

Comment: @UmarFarooque if you see the cells code I tried in that way but I have nil error, I think I need to save and array of values but I don't know how to re-set values on load, can you explain me please?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should be like this.

1. Take an array [say boolArr] equal to the count of your `number` variable used in

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`

This array [boolArr] should contain the state of your boolean buttons ie. if they are on or off.

2. Save this [boolArr] when `viewwilldisappear` is called.
3. Load the data from the same array [boolArr] in the view will appear and use it further in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
4. Add necessary check for nil and empty when loading the data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.